# Params value on select dropdown in form returns nil

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, post

I have this in one of my forms. Everything else in my form submits correctly.

But when I try and get the value of params[:invest_with] I get nil? Why is this. This is the only select I have in the form so maybe I am not setting it correctly or something.

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only">Invest_With</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-addon">Invest with: </div>

          <select name="invest_with" class="form-control">
            <option name="invest_with" value="user">Your Personal Balance</option>
            <% n = 0 %>
            <% @lender_companies.each do |company| %>
              <% n += 1 %>
              <option name="invest_with" value="company <%= n %>"> <%= company.name %>'s Balance </option>
            <% end %>
          </select>

        </div>
      </div>
```

Here is my whole form:

```
<form class="form-inline" method="post" action="/private_investement" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only">Amount</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
      <input type="number" min="10" max="<%=@loan.pending%>" class="form-control" name="amount" placeholder="Amount" required>
    </div>
  </div>

<br><br>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-addon">Invest with: </div>

      <select name="invest_with" class="form-control" multiple required>
        <option value="user">Your Personal Balance</option>
        <%n=0%>
        <%@lender_companies.each do |company|%>
          <%n+=1%>
          <option value="company<%=n%>"><%=company.name%>'s Balance</option>
        <%end%>
      </select>

    </div>
  </div>


  <input type="hidden" name="loan_id" value="<%=@loan.id%>">
  <input type="hidden" name="company" value="<%=@company.name%>">
  <input type="hidden" name="loan_amount" value="<%=@loan.amount%>">
  <input type="hidden" name="investor_money" value="<%=current_user.balance%>">
  <input type="hidden" name="company_money" value="<%=@lender_company%>">

<br><br>
  <button type="sumbit" class="btn btn-primary">Invest</button><br>
  Once you press the invest button there is no coming back.
</form>
```

My question is how can I fix this?

Comment: Try removing the `name` attribute from the `select` tag or the `option` tags. I don't think you need both as the `option` tags are nested.

Comment: Also, you can replace `each` with `each_with_index`. That will give you `n` instead of you having to do it.

Comment: I tried have the name tags only on one and then only on the other, and it still doesn't work. How would I get the index number with each_with_index?

Comment: Change `|company|` to `|company, n|`. The second variable is your index. Can you post the params that are sent to the server?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want something like this. Without seeing the rest of the form it's hard to tell, but make sure you have the name attribute set correctly; check the other elements generated by the form as you might need to set the name to something like `user[invset_with]`

```
<%= select_tag 'invest_with',
    options_for_select(@lender_companies.map{ |c| [c.name, "company #{c.id}"] }),
    {include_blank: 'Your Personal Balance', multiple: true, required: true, class: 'form-control'}
%>
```

Also make sure you are [permitting](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Parameters/permit) the `:invest_with` parameter

**EDIT**

Upon posting a simplified verion of your form I am given the following in the terminal:

`Started POST "/private_investement" for ::1 at 2015-08-09 17:41:51 -0400
Processing by StaticPagesController#private_investement as HTML
  Parameters: {"amount"=>"13", "invest_with"=>["company1", "company3"], "loan_id"=>"77", "company"=>"company.name", "loan_amount"=>"loan.amount", "investor_money"=>"balance", "company_money"=>"lender_company"}`

If you would be so kind as to supply what your logs contain.

Comment: If I set the name to something like this: user[invset_with], how would I get the value of the selected item in my application controller?

Comment: If you're not going to use the rails `select_tag` helper and plan to use the `multiple` attribute you will need to change the name of the select element. Replace `name="post[invest_with]"` with `name="invest_with[]"`

Comment: Besides what I've mentioned in my previous comment, I was able to recreate your form without any issue of calling `params[:invest_with]` on the posted to private_investement action.

Comment: I am still getting:
>> params[:invest_with]
=> nil

Comment: This is my termina, no parameter for invest_withl:
Started POST "/private_investement" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-10 01:05:03 +0200
Processing by InvestController#private_investement as HTML
  Parameters: {"amount"=>"2500", "loan_id"=>"10", "company"=>"Pabi & Co", "loan_amount"=>"5000.0", "user_money"=>"25000.0", "company_money"=>""}